# Bootstrap Modal Dynamic Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to define a bootstrap modal that gets a dynamic width regarding its content and if necessary a vertical scrollbar.

The vertical scrollbar works but the horizontal width seems to be a fixed width. Could you please help?
Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Dynamic Modal Title</h4></div>
      <div class="modal-body">Dynamic Modal Body</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">Dynamic Modal Footer</div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS:

```
.modal .modal-body { /* Vertical scrollbar if necessary */
    max-height: 480px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body .modal-dialog { /* Width */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`inline-block` elements get dynamic width regarding their content.

```
body .modal-dialog { /* Width */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note: `width: auto !important;` is required to overwrite bootstrap css.
Finally to place it in middle of viewport you to `display: flex;` on the parent element

```
.modal {
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-open .modal {
   z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to define the horizontal alignment in another way then with text-align? All my dialogs are already written and they don't contain information to align text left which would be much work to define this.

Comment: Yes, you can add .modal-dialog .modal-content {  text-align: left; } to revert it for modal content.

Comment: What would this be for Bootstrap 4. How would you do the `.modal.in{
     text-align: center;
}` ?

Comment: @gaitat I would use flexbox

Comment: This approach makes the modal jump back to the left side on hiding. It looks like it only knows how to fade out on the left, not in the centre. :(

Comment: display: flex !important; is blocking the click events

Comment: @Enrique I updated the answer. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8kh3qgc/3/

Comment: Actually the solution is in Vael Victus answer, just use "text-aling: center"

Answer (score 19):

@tmg's answer will only work for Bootstrap 3. **For Bootstrap 4**, use this:

```
.modal {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Alongside his suggestion:

```
.modal-dialog {
    text-align: left; /* you'll likely want this */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`fit-content` worked well for me with no ill side effects like a misplaced modal.

```
.modal {
    padding: 1%;
}
.modal-lg {
    min-width: auto;
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works in Bootstrap 5:

```css
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamedeus/dauceqv1/5/)

Note the margin styles are only necessary for iOS Safari, `fit-content` is sufficient on all other platforms tested.

Answer (score 3):

Works in Bootstrap 4-

Here I have added min width to 300px, max width to 90vw, modal can be scrolled vertically using screen scrollbar, and horizontal scrollbar shows up on modal if content width is > 90vw

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.modal-body { /* Restrict Modal width to 90% */
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  max-width: 90vw !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only needed it for `modal-lg` and `modal-xl`. Here is how I fixed it:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .modal-dialog.modal-xl{
    max-width: min( 90vw, 1200px ) !important;
  }
  .modal-dialog.modal-lg{
    max-width: min( 90vw, 900px ) !important;
  }
}
```