# Fit PartialView to Bootstrap Modal (MVC)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm displaying a MVC Partial View inside a Bootstrap Modal by clicking a button. My setup is like this:

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="Preview">
                @*PartialView*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Open() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("PartialViewTitle", "Controller")',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Preview').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In my Controller I have defined a method **PartialViewTitle()** which returns the Partial View. I have a button, where **onclick=** links to the **Open()** function.

The problem is that the content of my partial View is displayed on the left side of the modal and on the right is blank space. I would like to have the size of my modal adapted to its content and the content to be centered. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content centered you just have to add align-self-center as follow:

```
<div class="modal-body align-self-center" id="Preview">
```

To adapt size, you can use css display: inline-block; please take a look to the following article:

[Bootstrap Modal Dynamic Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307647/bootstrap-modal-dynamic-width)

Comment: Your link helped to solve my problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `.cshtml` view use

```
<div id='myModal' class='modal hide fade in' data-url='@Url.Action("PartialViewTitle","Controller")'>
   <div id='ModalContainer'>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Open() {
            var url = $('#myModal').data('url');             
            $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#ModalContainer').html(data);

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
        }
    </script>
```

If it doesn't work then need to add styles.

Comment: Unfortunately with this setup my modal doesn't open..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('#Preview').append(data);` instead of `$('#Preview').html(data);`

Comment: If I use this, I have to clear the Modal afterwards. Otherwise it appends the data multiple times.